# what does <native> keyword in Adobe extendscript

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript

I tried to learn Adobe CEP develop.
When I learn the source code, I found  key words in the javaScript code.
I don't know what does it mean.
Please check the screenshot as below.
[image]

Please get more source code from the link as below.
https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/CEP-Resources/blob/master/CEP_9.x/CEPEngine_extensions.js